# What is the difference between a regular join and a subquery join?

Tags: mysql, sql

What is the difference between a regular join and a subquery join?

```
1. SELECT * FROM city c LEFT JOIN street s ON s.city_id = c.id
```

vs

```
2. SELECT * FROM city c LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM street) s ON s.city_id = c.id
```

This is of course simple example.
I know - with subquery in JOIN I can add where, group by etc, but what is the difference in such a simple example?

Comment: Well the results should be same no difference  there, but the second query can be slower as MySQL can [materialize](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-table-optimization.html) the delivered table (subquery) , this also depends on MySQL version what will happen as more modern MySQl optimizers would tend to avoid the materializion where possible by factoring out (manual calls it merging)  the subquery as the subquery is 100% redundant in this simple case.

Comment: There are major differences, but those depends on the specific subquery example. There's no general rule.